# How do I specify an existence condition in an if statement using wildcards?

Tags: bash, if-statement, for-loop

I have the following statement in a bash script running on an Ubuntu box:

```
for l in foo_????
do
     # do something with $l
done
```

This does not work properly if there are no files that match the pattern.

I prepended the for loop with:

```
if [ -f foo_??? ]
then
   for l in foo_???
```

It works if there are 0 or 1 files matching the pattern, but fails when there are more with the message `line 4: [: foo_123: binary operator expected`

How do I need to modify this block to only loop if there are >= 1 files matching the pattern?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If there are no files that match the pattern and you don't want the loop to fail, set the `nullglob` directive:

```
~/foo $ echo *
*
~/foo $ shopt -s nullglob
~/foo $ echo *

~/foo $
```

The reason your `if` statement failed is the same as the reason your `for` loop failed: the unexpanded glob was still there. If you want a `sh` compliant version of your script you can use an `if` statement in lieu of the `nullglob` directive, but you have to adjust it:

```
for file in foo_???; do
    if [ -f "$file" ]; then
        …
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 1):

rather than testing whether the pattern you have has expanded correctly you use some constructs that make sure that you are only getting existing files matchin your pattern.

e.g.

```
 find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "foo_???" | while read file
 do
     ...
 done
```